# Как проверить на дубль в Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine2, symfony-form

В laravel есть метод чтобы можно было не записывать дубли:

```
`User::firstOrCreate(array(
    'name' => $input['name'],
    'email' => $input['email'],
    'password' => $input['password'])
);`
```

Помогите пожалуйста как можно это сделать на symfony 4

Comment: а почему `firstOrCreate`? а если я создам второго пользователя (такого-же) но с другим паролем?

Comment: Смысл не в том что написано в коде, это просто пример. Мне надо просто сделать валидацию на symfony чтобы не пропускал дубли, а дубль может быть при совпадение от двух и более значений

Comment: Doctrine не Eloquent, которая является AR, здесь не нарушается SRP.
Да еще и создавать сущность из массива - нечто странное. Сейчас даже официально плохим тоном считается умываться setter-ами, getter-ами в сущности, т.к. они делают из нее тупую структуру, а это бизнес.

Comment: https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/33 - вот как делают, когда можно взять laravel и дописать мини-блог на нем уже.

https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/37 - вот как делать правильно, удобно, практично, целесообразно

А вы тут про создание сущностей из массивов, коллега.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно зарегистрировать собственный сервис, в котором прописать метод, решающий задачу.

Более правильным считается добавить валидацию на уникальность сущности (работает, если не ошибаюсь только с Doctrine). https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: Насколько я знаю UniqueEntity проверяет уникальность только одно сущности, а мне надо чтобы сочеталось дублем если совпадает два и более столбца

Comment: в параметрах валидатора, отдельной опцией можно (нужно) указать, по какому набору полей проверять уникальность. Их может быть сколько угодно (в пределах свойств сущности) https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил этого в документации